# Anylogic Excel Row in Parameter

Tags: excel, anylogic

I have an Excel File which I like to use to fill my parameter. The Excel file is an output so I don't want to change something on the formation of the file.

For my first parameter I want to import all values of the certain row in the Excel file. For example all values for all years of row 3. I already created a parameter as army with the years as dimension but doesn't know how to get the values in the best way. Maybe someone can help me.

[image: Excel Sheet]

Comment: Add a screenshot of your table so that it's easier to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume number of years equal to 30 and you have an array p[] with years as dimension:

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < 30 ; i++)
{
p[i] = excelFile.getCellNumericValue(1, 3, i + 3);
i++;
}
```

Comment: It depends. If you are initializing your model at the very beginning and the Excel file is ready before the model run, then you can write this in main's "On Startup" field.

Comment: the file is ready before model run, but would it be a mistake to do it in the event also in this case?

Comment: No it is not a fundamental mistake... Just make sure you do it before you use the parameter anywhere else.